# Rails 3 Object.try Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a field that may be blank, so I need to use Object.try, but I'm having trouble with the syntax when adding the date format.

```
<%= @request.assigned_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>
```

How would I change the above to include the ".try" ?

Thanks in advance. Katie

Comment: The answers below are accurate but wanted to also point out you can do this on hashes as well (or just about any object). Example, `params['user']['name']` can rely on `.try` and be represented as `params.try(:[], 'user').try(:[], 'name')`.

Comment: `params['user'].try(:[], 'name')` would be enough if you're in a rails controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say...

```
<%= @request.assigned_date.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%y") %>
```

Note that it wouldn't work if your field was an empty string. It has to be nil.

Answer (score 2):

I would try:

```
<%= @request.assigned_date.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%y") %>
```

Tell me if that worked for you.